# Why do I get the site running at whatever interface I choose as proxy regardless of the domain requested?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy

```
Linux Kernel: 4.9.163-lxpup-32-pae (i686)
Kernel Version: #1 SMP Thu Mar 14 15:41:19 GMT 2019
Build GCC: 8.3.0
Distro: BionicPup32 19.03
busybox: 1.30.1
dhcpcd: 6.7.1
Firewall: Off (ip_tables not active)
Network Interface:  virtualLAN
```

modprobe dummy interfaces named `virtualLAN(192.168.1.100)` and `virtualWAN(192.168.2.100)`.
Not a thing in resolv.conf or host.conf; blank. ALL, and the only DNS configs are in dnsmasq and dnsmasq2.conf in dnsmasq.d directory.

```
dnsmasq.conf
interface=virtualLAN
listen-address=192.168.1.100
address=/lanwebsite/192.168.1.100

dnsmasq2.conf is in /etc/dnsmasq.d
interface=virtualWAN
listen-address=192.168.2.100
address=/wanwebsite/192.168.2.100
```

On both config files #bind-interfaces and #localise-queries are commented out and so are off.
No internet connection sharing or forwarding rules between the 2 interfaces LAN and WAN.

virtualLAN is the active interface as per puppyLinux ipInfo
Dnsmasq daemon is running and no firewalls.

2 websites are running.
Lanwebsite on 192.168.1.100(virtualLAN interface) and wanwebsite on 192.168.2.100(virtualWAN interface)

**NOW**, with browser configured to proxy via WAN on `192.168.2.100` the expectation is requesting for

> "lanwebsite"

domain by typing that into the browser with current configuration should fetch lansite correctly.
But I'm getting the

> "wanwebsite"

ip address (192.168.2.100). But if I repeat the same with no proxy or proxy as `virtualLAN`, I get correct ip address.

V/versa is true if I proxy via LAN and ask for "wanwebsite."  I get the LAN website.

I get the site running at whatever interface I choose as proxy. If proxy is .2.100, request for

> lanwebsite

gives ip for

> wanwebsite

(.2.100) and if proxy is 1.100, request for

> wanwebsite

gives ip for

> lanwebsite

(1.100)

But if I ask for

> gI*7bb3rishSit3

for example, I correctly get an error. Proxy or no proxy, and no matter which proxy.

*Suspected issues: *bind interfaces/Localise DNS queries, *DNS Caching(tried dnsmasq clear cache on reload) *Browser caching. All tried, same results.
OR issue with dummy interfaces not quite being interface as such. Thing with dummy vs tun/tap? I'mma be tryin that in the meantime. Meanwhile, help?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the web proxy using a dns server returning local site instead of NXDOMAIN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1108305/why-is-the-web-proxy-using-a-dns-server-returning-local-site-instead-of-nxdomain)

Comment: No. But I solved it and I have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the host machine is routing to all interfaces via interface `lo` and listening on all interfaces. So when I run multiple DNS servers on the same host, and the requests get routed via interface `lo`, the port 53 listener there is the one that responds.

- **SOLUTION:**
  Used ip net namespaces to separate the interfaces into separate domains, `veth`ed them together, then ran separate instances of DNSMasq in the separate namespaces. There.